# Undefined references in c++ project

Tags: c++, makefile

I have 5 files, namely : Dice.cpp, Dice.h, Pokemon.cpp, Pokemon.h, and main.cpp. The following is what I've included in each file:

Dice.cpp

```
#include "Dice.h"
```

Dice.h

```
#ifndef DICE_H
#define DICE_H
#include <cstdio> /** NULL */
#include <cstdlib> /** srand(), rand() */
#include <ctime> /** time() */
```

Pokemon.cpp

```
#include "Pokemon.h"
#include <string>
#include "Dice.h"

Pokemon::Pokemon() {
healthPoints = attackL = defL =0;
std::string Pname= "";
d20=Dice(20);
d6=Dice(6);
    }
```

Pokemon.h

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Dice.h"
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Pokemon.h"
#include "Dice.h"
```

## makefile

```
all: Lab02

Lab02: main.o Pokemon.o Dice.o
    g++ main.o Pokemon.o Dice.o -o Lab02

main.o: main.cpp
    g++ -c main.cpp

Pokemon.o: Pokemon.cpp
    g++ -c Pokemon.cpp

Dice.o: Dice.cpp
    g++ -c Dice.cpp

clean:
    rm  *o Lab02
```

### Errors

When I try to build the application using geany I get the following errors:

```
>g++ -Wall -o "main" "main.cpp"
>/tmp/ccd3vy1j.o: In function `main':
>main.cpp:(.text+0x19): undefined reference to `Pokemon::Pokemon()'
>main.cpp:(.text+0x28): undefined reference to `Pokemon::Pokemon()'
>main.cpp:(.text+0x3c): undefined reference to `Dice::Dice(int)'
>main.cpp:(.text+0x83): undefined reference to `Pokemon::userBuild()'
>main.cpp:(.text+0xca): undefined reference to `Pokemon::userBuild()'
>main.cpp:(.text+0xd9): undefined reference to `Dice::roll()'
>main.cpp:(.text+0x1b0): undefined reference to `Pokemon::getname()'
>main.cpp:(.text+0x1c9): undefined reference to `Pokemon::getname()'
>main.cpp:(.text+0x259): undefined reference to `Pokemon::attack(Pokemon)'
>main.cpp:(.text+0x290): undefined reference to `Pokemon::getname()'
>main.cpp:(.text+0x31b): undefined reference to `Pokemon::attack(Pokemon)'
>main.cpp:(.text+0x34f): undefined reference to `Pokemon::getname()'
>main.cpp:(.text+0x452): undefined reference to `Pokemon::getname()'
>main.cpp:(.text+0x46b): undefined reference to `Pokemon::getname()'
>main.cpp:(.text+0x4f5): undefined reference to `Pokemon::attack(Pokemon)'
>main.cpp:(.text+0x529): undefined reference to `Pokemon::getname()'
>main.cpp:(.text+0x5b4): undefined reference to `Pokemon::attack(Pokemon)'
>main.cpp:(.text+0x5e8): undefined reference to `Pokemon::getname()'
>main.cpp:(.text+0x655): undefined reference to `Pokemon::getHP()'
>main.cpp:(.text+0x668): undefined reference to `Pokemon::getHP()'
>collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
>Compilation failed.
```

#### Terminal Output

```
Lab02
g++ -c main.cpp
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:35:5: error: expected ‘}’ before ‘else’
     else if (attackL1 <= 0) {
     ^
main.cpp:37:11: error: expected primary-expression before ‘>’ token
      cin>>>attackL1;
           ^
main.cpp: At global scope:
main.cpp:43:2: error: ‘cout’ does not name a type
  cout<<"Enter your defense level (1-30): ";
  ^
main.cpp:44:3: error: ‘cin’ does not name a type
   cin>>defPoints1;
   ^
main.cpp:46:4: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘if’
    if (defPoints1 > 49) {
    ^
make: *** [main.o] Error 1
```

Can someone point me in the right direction as to why I can't build the file? I'm pretty sure there's something wrong with my makefile but I can't figure out what. Thanks

Comment: Did you *implement* everything declared in those headers somewhere? Including them in a .cpp is all well and good, but are the declared members actually *implemented* as well ?

Comment: I've edited my post. I _implemented_ the Pokemon::Pokemon as well as all the other members. I can edit and add more examples if required but I just didn't want to make a huge post.

Comment: Can you post a full `make` run as well, I.e. the output of a `make` after a `make clean`? The order of your linkage looks correct (most to least dependent), as linking can be finicky at times. Thanks.

Comment: That's the terminal output right? I've been compiling and building within Geany and the errors above are the output. I will try to 'make' it in terminal

Comment: make Lab02
g++ -c main.cpp
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:35:5: error: expected ‘}’ before ‘else’
     else if (attackL1 <= 0) {
     ^
main.cpp:37:11: error: expected primary-expression before ‘>’ token
      cin>>>attackL1;
           ^
main.cpp: At global scope:
main.cpp:43:2: error: ‘cout’ does not name a type
  cout<<"Enter your defense level (1-30): ";
  ^
main.cpp:44:3: error: ‘cin’ does not name a type
   cin>>defPoints1;
   ^
main.cpp:46:4: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘if’
    if (defPoints1 > 49) {
    ^
make: *** [main.o] Error 1

Comment: Not as a wall of text in a comment please. Update the question, thought the errors aren't exactly looking promising.

Comment: Yeah sorry, I couldn't figure out how to format it. I will add the output to the question.

Comment: Actually, it doesn't matter at this point (though it would be interesting to see). The line above your output for the error messages is telling enough. **`g++ -Wall -o "main" "main.cpp"`** says its compiling `main.cpp`, then immediately linking to `main` from the output object code. I.e geany is not aware of the other file dependencies in your project. I'm not familiar with how that tool is used, but apparently it is make file agnostic to your setup of `Makefie`, which appears correct, btw.

Comment: I didn't use Geany to build it. I ran the `make` command from a terminal window and just copy and pasted the output. So do you think it's an issue with the compiler not my `makefile`?

Comment: No, I think it s an issue with geany. Your makefile looks right (can't say much about the code in your source files) but it almost looks like geany is kicking off a compile of `main.cpp` (which main.cpp we don't know), then attempting to link the resulting object code all in a single step. I think its a config problem with geany. Example: note the line of code in your makefile that is responsible for compiling main.cpp. `g++ -c main.cpp` you don't see that *anywhere* in your geany run.

Comment: Geany has the following commands `compile, build, make, and execute`
When I run build is when I get the `undefined references` error. However, when I run make it returns `compilation finished successfully` and when I `execute` I get an error # 127.

Answer (score 0):

First, try `make clean` followed by `make`.  If a header file were revised, the makefile would not sense that and rebuild the class properly.

More likely, you haven't declared `class Pokemon` and `class Dice` properly.  Maybe show the declarations for these.

Main.c refers the symbols listed in the error message.  Maybe they are named differently (C++ is case sensitive), or the class's scope is hidden.

Comment: This is the declaration for 'class Pokemon' 
'class Pokemon {
 
 private:
  int healthPoints, hitPoints, attackL, defL;
  
  std::string Pname;
  Dice d20;
  Dice d6;
  
 public:
  Pokemon();
  bool attack(Pokemon opponent);
  void userBuild();"